# Silent print from an UWP (javascript) application

Tags: javascript, windows, printing, uwp

I'm facing a problem with an UWP application.
I need to "silent print" pdf file from my application. By "silent print", I mean that I don't want to display the windows print dialog before printing.

I have already made it works with the dialog, no problem. But now, I'm searching for a way to directly create my printTask and send it to the right printer with the right properties, without prompt it to the user.

Unfortunately, I dont find a workaround for this... 
If anyone has an idea ? A native UWP solution ? A windows runtime ? An other solution ?

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to print without the print preview dialog.

Comment: There should be something like: await Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager.PrintAsync();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Silent print from an UWP Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984595/how-to-silent-print-from-an-uwp-application)

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984595/how-to-silent-print-from-an-uwp-application/