# How to Silent print from an UWP Application

Tags: uwp

I am trying to make a Print application on UWP, but the samples show

```
await Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
```

This brings the UWP Print Dialog.

I need to print directly without this dialog. How to do this?

I need something like

```
await Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager.PrintAsync();
```

We should be able to programatically list printers, select the printer, configure paper size, orientation, settings...

Comment: This is on UserVoice https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/6185763-allow-direct-printing-without-modern-ui-print-dial

Comment: It's been on UserVoice for FOUR YEARS now. This is insane...

Comment: This is a WinUI Proposal: Allow the App to Print without showing the Confirmation Dialog to user https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2126

Answer (score 8):

The current UWP API does not support silent printing, i.e. without explicit user interaction.

For POS scenarios UWP does offer the POSPrinter API - this may or may not apply to your scenario though:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.PointOfService.PosPrinter

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PosPrinter

For LOB applications running on desktop, you also have the option to continue using your Win32 printing APIs from a fulltrust process included in your UWP app package. I have put together a quick sample that demonstrates this technique in the example of printing image files silently from a UWP:

Store: https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9pd51nnkx3t2

Source: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AovTwKUMywTNnOsbzlRfghOikDy8Dw

It's certainly a valid feature request and we should extend the API to enable this scenario with the right user model in place (API, capability, settings, etc.) to ensure a proper user experience.

Please vote here on UserVoice to help the team prioritize the feature:
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/6185763-allow-direct-printing-without-modern-ui-print-dial

Comment: Also, in WPF I used to specify Print Sizes of the Page and printed objects (Border) in cm, for example.

Comment: Best app description ever. "Sample to demonstrate interop with Win32 printing API"

Comment: I think it is a good feature, please create the API, capability, settings, etc. needed to programatically select the Printer then Silent Print on UWP. See https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/6185763-allow-direct-printing-without-modern-ui-print-dial

Comment: Is UserVoice still the best place to go for this? I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure out how to get a Zebra printer to work with UWP.

Comment: @eltiare The feature is still in the backlog. More votes will help the print team prioritize. The only workaround for now is to use a desktop extension process like I am doing in my simple image printing demo above.

Answer (score 3):

I am using RawPrint nuget to print silently in UWP:

https://github.com/frogmorecs/RawPrint

Sample:

```
  ...

  if (file != null)
  {
      IPrinter printer = new Printer();
      var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
      printer.PrintRawStream("Brother DCP-L2540DN series Printer", stream, file.DisplayName);
  }
```

Comment: Old thread, but I as far as I can see, this does not suport UWP?

Comment: @AdamMcMahon it supports it but only if you run it in Windows (win32). It will not work on a Arm device for example.

Answer (score 2):

> await Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager.PrintAsync();

As far as I know, there is no such api for printer without `PrintUI`. And I search some similar [issues](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/09494c07-9711-4bbe-9bff-3249b65eb920/uwpc-how-to-design-an-app-where-you-can-print-to-default-printer-without-showing-the-print-ui?forum=wpdevelop). And the answer is negative. If you do want this feature, you are welcome to vote up on the [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/6185763-allow-direct-printing-without-modern-ui-print-dial) .

Comment: True in general, there is a few nuances to this though. Let me offer another answer to this.

Comment: Yes.Please go ahead.