# UWP to print without Print preview

Tags: c#, printing, uwp

In my UWP application, I wanted to print a document without showing the print UI.
Normally we use  `PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync()`
But I wanted to print without showing the UI. 
In my Research, I found that there's no such thing in UWP to print directly without showing Preview. But it can be done through 
**FullTrustProces Launcher** (or) **Brokered Component**.
I am unaware of both of this 2 processes. Can someone tell me the way to use them in detail or any other way to get print without showing the Preview or sending stream directly to the Printer?

Edit1: Someone tageed it as a duplicate, so i explained the difference between the 2 questions.
It's not the duplicate of that question. My question clearly asks which process shall i use whether the FullTrustProcess Launcher or Brokered Component. The question that person tagged is asking whether there's a way to print silently. But my question is which method is best.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Silent print from an UWP Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984595/how-to-silent-print-from-an-uwp-application)

Comment: @Rafael it's not the duplicate of that question. My question clearly asks which process shall i use whether the **FullTrustProcess Launcher** or **Brokered Component**. The question You tagged is asking whether there's a way to print silently. But my question is which method is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter **FullTrustProces Launcher (or) Brokered Component** technology, they all call win32 APIs to achieve the silent print.

For the FullTrustProces Launcher, it actually is putting a win32 process in your UWP app package. The win32 process could be console application, Windows Forms app etc. Stefan has replied a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47018904/6782612). On that thread, Stefan has explained and provided a simple code sample, please check it.

You could also refer to this blog [Desktop Bridge – The Migrate phase: invoking a Win32 process from a UWP app](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2016/12/19/desktop-bridge-the-migrate-phase-invoking-a-win32-process-from-a-uwp-app/) for more details.

For the Brokered Windows Runtime Components, it makes side-loaded Universal Windows Platform apps to interoperate with desktop processes outside of the app container possible. Please see [Brokered Windows Runtime Components for a side-loaded UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps#introduction) for more details.

Comment: our application is side loaded UWP, so shall i write a WPF application to print silently and then migrate it through Desktop Bridge or use Brokered Win RT ?
If it is Brokered Win RT, Can u please tell me the way to use it, as i am unable to do it through microsoft docs

Comment: @Hariprasadkasavajjala In general, it's simpler to use Desktop Bridge. You could check the sample on my above reply