# Silent printing in UWP follow up

Tags: c#, printing, uwp

Last year Stefan Wick provided an answer to a question about silent printing in UWP applications [How to silent print from a UWP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984595/how-to-silent-print-from-an-uwp-application), along with a sample app showing a [solution](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AovTwKUMywTNnOsbzlRfghOikDy8Dw).

That app won't work for me, as it can't access local settings.  The error is that it needs `Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract` 3.0.0.0. The UWP project has access to that, but the Win32 project does not, and I can't figure out how to reference it (Nuget won't recognize it and I can't find a viable dll to download).

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Or any alternatives to get UWP to print directly to a USB connected receipt printer without requiring the user to see the print preview dialog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the `Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract` directly from the `References` folder in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\`. Specifically this library is in the `10.0.17763.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\3.0.0.0` subfolder.

For more info on how to reference the libraries see this [blogpost](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/).

Comment: Thank you!  I'm old school enough that I was looking for a dll instead of a winmd.

Comment: Sure thing, glad it helped!